# NODE_SHARED_MODE and __POSIX__

Tags: node.js, v8, event-loop, libuv

What is the role of NODE_SHARED_MODE and **POSIX** macros in node.js source code ? 
In which file they are defined?

These are present in node_main.cc in nodejs src directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GitHub's search feature (or `grep` in a local checkout) to search through Node.js's source code:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=NODE_SHARED_MODE

[https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=**POSIX**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=__POSIX__)

And you will find that both symbols are defined in `node.gypi`. From reading the surrounding code in that file, you can also deduce the conditions under which they are defined.